How to clear autocomplete list in the Windows 11 Run dialog?
I had exactly the same problem as KrisReynolds here; but in Windows 11: Windows 10 Run Dialog - Autocompleting
He writes:

When using the Windows 10 Run Dialog, as soon as I start typing, it
displays various files and folders - even ones that have never been
opened!
For example, if I type "d:", it will immediately display
"d:\folder\file.ext" and so on.
There is nothing in the Run dialog history (checked registry and run
CCleaner) I've disabled the autocomplete option in IE

In addition I think it doesn't always show all files from some folders. Some of the listed files are from USB-stick which is not plugged in and the drive letter has been changed after that a number of times. So it is not a realtime file listing, but some sort of saved history.
Like Kris, I tried clearing Explorer Recents, searched through Registry, edited various MRU settings in Registry and Group Policy Editor. Even installed MRU Blaster and ran full scan. No effect.
There'sa an answer there by w32sh and it does work in Windows 11:

Click Start Regedit.exe and go to the following branch:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoComplete
Double-click AutoSuggest and set its value data to no
If the value AutoSuggest doesn't already exist, create the new String value (REG_SZ) manually and set its data to no

Setting HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoComplete\AutoSuggest back to yes shows the same files again in Run Dialog.
What if one wants to clear this list?
Anybody out there who knows of whereabouts of this list?
